# Convert shape of an array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

[image]
How do i convert y's format from the above to the one below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `reshape`:

```
>>> y = np.random.random((200,1))
>>> y.shape
(200, 1)
>>> y = y.reshape(200,)
>>> y.shape
(200,)
```

Or `flatten`:

```
>>> y = y.flatten()
>>> y.shape
(200,)
```